# What could be the reason for Okta Log Api giving internal Server Error 500 through code but giving result when run from Postman

Tags: api, okta, okta-api

I have a windows service which hits Okta Event Api

http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/events.html

Now I have changed code to hit Okta Log Api

http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/system_log.html

Problem : While Log api Get request works fine from postman tool it gives "Internal Server Error 500" when i run it from Code. The previous Event Api works perfectly fine from code and postman both.

This is what I get in response: 
{"errorCode":"E0000009","errorSummary":"Sorry, there's been an error. We aren't sure what caused it, but we've logged this and will work to address it. Please try your request again.","errorId":"7f997bbe-7a31-4431-9f42-ae40db5200ac"}

What could be a possible reason for this?

Comment: Can you paste in the code you're trying?

Comment: curl --request GET \
  --url https://<ORG-NAME>.oktapreview.com/api/v1/logs \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'authorization: SSWS <TOKEN>' \
  --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' <--- This works for me.